# Checked radio input (only those which contain a value) inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is my code:

```
<?php 

if(!empty($wpjobus_resume_skills)) {

for ($i = 0; $i < (count($wpjobus_resume_skills)); $i++) {

?>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
       <span>20%</span>
       <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class="checkedClass<?php echo $i; ?>" id='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='20%' class='slider_value'>
    </div>


    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span>40%</span>
        <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class="checkedClass<?php echo $i; ?>" id='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='40%' class='slider_value'>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span>60%</span>                                    
        <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class="checkedClass<?php echo $i; ?>" id='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='60%' class='slider_value'>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span>80%</span>
        <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class="checkedClass<?php echo $i; ?>" id='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='80%' class='slider_value'>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span>100%</span>
        <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class="checkedClass<?php echo $i; ?>" id='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='100%' class='slider_value'>                          
    </div>
```

ok. I am storing my data in a post meta var `wpjobus_resume_skills`. I want to only checked the inputs which contains a value. for example on 1st iteration of the for loop, the input with 80% value should be checked as i have 80% in my var `$wpjobus_resume_skills[$i][1]`. In the second loop lets say 40% is saved then i want to only checked that 40% input.

**screenshot:**
should be like this

[image]

this is what i am trying which checked all the values:

```
<?php
if( !empty($wpjobus_resume_skills[$i][1]) )
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('.checkedClass<?php echo $i; ?>').prop('checked', true);
    </script>
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

my array:  `print_r($wpjobus_resume_skills);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => C++
            [1] => 40%
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Java
            [1] => 60%
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rails
            [1] => 80%
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => HTML 5
            [1] => 100%
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Android
            [1] => 20%
        )

)
```

**This worked for me:**

adding this to the input tag `<?php echo ($wpjobus_resume_skills[$i][1]=='100%')?'checked':'';?>`

```
<input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class="checkingtheclass checkedClass<?php echo $i; ?>" id='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' <?php echo ($wpjobus_resume_skills[$i][1]=='100%')?'checked':'';?> value='100%' class='slider_value'>
```

Comment: not like this:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/vtLZ3.png

Comment: Why javascript? On your html you can say that if data has value you can print checked=checked

Comment: @Marco Mura no then the result would be like this  [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vtLZ3.png)

Comment: When do you want it to be selected? After what? When you have the data?

Comment: What's in $wpjobus_resume_skills ? + you want javascript solution or html solution?

Comment: wait i will show my array.

Comment: @Naruto Mura i echod my variable check above

Comment: i just want the solution both are suitable for me

Comment: php solution or javascript one? (as @Naruto as asked)

Comment: php or javascript any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with PHP code.

Inside your loop add this check in each tag.

```
   <?php echo ($wpjobus_resume_skills[$i][1]=='YOUR_VALUE')?'checked':'';?>
```

For example

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($wpjobus_resume_skills)); $i++) {
?>
<input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class="checkedClass<?php echo 
   $i; ?>" id='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' 
  name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='80%' 
 class='slider_value'      <?php echo ($wpjobus_resume_skills[$i][1]=='80%')?'checked':'';?>

 >
 .
```

Comment: i didn't understand your answer

Comment: whats this '<?=' why the = sign?

Comment: These are short tags.I have edited.What you have to do copy paste that condition in each tag and change 80% value with relevant value..

Comment: @HassanAli - `<?= $variable ?>` is shorthand for `<?php echo $variable ?>`

Comment: yup actually i always use the full '<?php' tag thats why i didn't knew about this '<?=' thanks alot i learned a new thing today :)

Answer (score 0):

give your checkbox the same class no need to change classes for each input
this function in jquery to check your checkbox with value you want

```
 function checkValue(Num){
        $('.checkIT').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == Num){
               $(this).prop('checked',true);
               }
        });
    }
```

you can call function with

```
checkValue('80%'); // change number as you want
```

see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s94xhnw6/5/)

replace your code with this

```
<?php 

if(!empty($wpjobus_resume_skills)) {

for ($i = 0; $i < (count($wpjobus_resume_skills)); $i++) {

?>
<div id="lang<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
       <span>20%</span>
       <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class='wpjobus_resume_skills' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='20%'>
    </div>


    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span>40%</span>
        <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class='wpjobus_resume_skills' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='40%'>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span>60%</span>                                    
        <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class='wpjobus_resume_skills' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='60%'>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span>80%</span>
        <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class='wpjobus_resume_skills' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='80%' />
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span>100%</span>
        <input style="width:50%; float: none" type='checkbox' class='wpjobus_resume_skills' name='wpjobus_resume_skills[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]' value='100%' >                          
    </div>
</div>
```

in js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  checkValue('lang1','20%');
  checkValue('lang2','80%');
  checkValue('lang3','100%');
});
function checkValue(IDname,Num){
    $('#'+IDname +' .wpjobus_resume_skills').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == Num){
           $(this).prop('checked',true);
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: nothing appearing on my side. i have add your code above please check what i am doing wrong.

Comment: try it without php to check it first  and add class checkIT  to your inputs

Comment: i got the answer above but i want to know your solution too. i like this solution too.